# Turn on/off mobile network connection programmatically in android jelly bean

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-networking

I am using below code to turn on/off mobile network.

```
        final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
        final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
        iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
        final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
        final Class iConnectivityManagerClass =  Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
        final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, ON);
```

I tested this code with Android 2.3.X, 4.0.X and 4.1.X. It is working with only 2.3.X and 4.0.X but **failed with 4.1.X**.

I am getting `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: mService` exception while testing with Android Jelly Bean.

Is there any other solution to my problem? I added all required permissions in manifest file.

Comment: Don't know if you need some other networks or if you want to work in non connected mode, but did you think about the airplane mode ?

Comment: Doesn't your phone need to be rooted for that?

Answer (score 2):

```
   try
              {
    dataMtd = ConnectivityManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", boolean.class);
              } 
              catch (SecurityException e1) 
              {

                e1.printStackTrace();
              } 
              catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) 
              {

                e1.printStackTrace();
              }

                dataMtd.setAccessible(true); 
               try {

                dataMtd.invoke(conm,true);



              } 
}
```

Where datamtd is a method.. Try with this my friend. I found it successful in my previous app. Hope this may help you. Sorry if not, since I'm not much experienced.:)

Comment: why do you cann dataMtd.setAccessible(true); **outside** the try catch block ? if getDeclaredMethod throws an Exception, dataMtd will be null and you'll crash

Comment: I've tried this already and the app is now available in the play store my friend. This is a piece of code from that one.

Comment: i am not saying it doesn't work, i'm just saying it is not logic/consistent. you catch an exception **because** there can be one, therefore you should consider the possibility completely.

Comment: also, while I agree that your answer should work (as I don't see the need to access the service when the method exists in the manager), I have looked at the source of this ConnectivityManager, and the field mService seems to be present from the start and was never removed.